# Yum won't update package

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

I am trying to update the package `minetest` from 0.4.9 to 0.4.10, but when I update the whole system, it states that there are no updates available.
If I try to update the package alone, I get the same output.

I already read, that I have to update `fedora-release`, but `yum` tells me it is up to date as well.

Does anyone have any idea why `yum` refuses to update `minetest`?

Comment: Add the output of `yum repolist all` to your question.

Comment: What version of Fedora is this? It's possible that telling you to update `fedora-release` was their way of telling you to upgrade to the next major release of Fedora.

Comment: They didn't tell me that, that's just what I read as answer to someone with the same question. I use Fedora 20, there were about three updates recently, and I did them all.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, there is no minetest 0.4.10 update for Fedora 20. I see that it's included in the new Fedora 21 release. You could also use my COPR, which tracks minetest development (roughly whenever I get around to updating it). See http://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/mattdm/minetest — there are builds for F19 and F20 as well as F21.